# Generics specifying both the interface and concrete class getting unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, generics

I have some code in testing where I need to pass both the interface and the concrete implementation through to a base class to ensure that only those methods on the interface are used in the testing code. I wish to get rid of the unchecked cast warning shown in the class hierarchy below.

```
public interface Intf<T> { ... }
public class Concrete<T> implements Intf<T>
public abstract class Base<T, I extends Intf<T>, C extends Concrete<T>> {
    protected I x;
    protected abstract Class<C> getImplClass();
    @Before
    public setUp {
        C impl = getImplClass().newInstance();
        ...
        x = (I) impl; // Unchecked Cast Warning Here
    }
}
```

Comment: Every cast to a generic parameter is unchecked due to type erasure.

Comment: The Fix is to get rid of the "I extends Intf<T>" and just change x's type from I to Intf<T>.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly declare

`protected abstract Class<I> getImplClass();`

and avoid casting.

Comment: But can you then guarantee that you can call getInstance on the returned class? You'ld have to trust future devs not to return the interface.

Comment: the same way as you were sure that `getInstance()` returns `C` when the return type was declared `Class<C>`.

Comment: But if the mythical future developer returns an Interface.class then getInstance will fail at runtime.

Comment: Is it a big difference, will it fail at `newInstance()` or a moment earlier, when `getImplClass()` returns?

Answer (score -1):

You can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` before the class or the method. 
But remember this only suppress these warnings.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this more for _neatness_ than anything.